# Импорт локальных пакетов в GO

Tags: golang

Есть такая структура файлов:

```
stdlib-basic/
├─ internal/
│  ├─ taskstore/
│     ├─ taskstore.go
├─ stdlib-basic.go
```

Как мне в stdlib-basic.go импортировать taskstore?

Пробовал `import "internal/taskstore"`
Пишет: "could not import internal/taskstore (cannot find package "internal/taskstore" in any of
C:\Program Files\Go\src\internal\taskstore (from $GOROOT)
C:\Users\usr\go\src\internal\taskstore (from $GOPATH))"

Понимаю, что через путь он пытается из главной директории достать пакет, но как мне дать ему понять, что я про текущую директорию?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Оказывается, в начале пути нужно было указать еще название модуля из go.mod

То есть, для файла

```
module stdserver

go 1.15
```

Импорт будет такой:

```
import "stdserver/internal/taskstore"
```